# Правильное выделение памяти под структуры

Tags: c, memory, struct, memory-management

Всем, доброго времени суток! Продолжаю своё медленное, но упорное знакомство с СИ.

Как правильней всего выделить память под структуру, в которой есть поле... Не уверен что правильный термин, но что-то вроде динамического поля. Смотрим код ниже.

```
typedef struct
{
   int count;
   char **arrays;
} _array_strs;

_array_strs *getArrayFromFile()
{
   FILE *fd = getFile(STORAGE, "r");
   char sym;
   char **arrays = (char **)getPtrMatrix(&sym, COUNT_WORDS, BUFF_WORD); 

   struct _array_strs *array_strs = (struct _array_strs *)calloc(sizeof(arrays) + sizeof(int), sizeof(struct array_strs));
   int i = 0;
   while (!feof(fd)) {
      fgets(arrays[i], BUFF_WORD, fd);
      i++;
   }

   array_strs->count = i;
   array_strs->arrays = arrays;

   fclose(fd);

   return array_strs;
}
```

Пару часов убил, много противоречивого нагуглил. Как не пробовал, но компилятор постоянно мною недоволен. При таком варианте кода, его ругательства выглядят следующим образом:

```
src/search.c: In function ‘getArrayFromFile’:
src/search.c:32:101: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct array_strs’
 struct _array_strs *array_strs = (struct _array_strs *)calloc(sizeof(arrays) + sizeof(int), sizeof(struct array_strs));
                                                                                                 ^
src/search.c:39:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct _array_strs’
 array_strs->count = i;
        ^
src/search.c:44:9: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 return array_strs;
```

Буду рад любой помощи компетентных специалистов. Всем добра!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас в программе нет такого типа, как `struct _array_strs`. Поэтому "выделить под него память" у вас не получится. При таком объявлении типа, как у вас, тип вашей структуры называется `_array_strs`, а не `struct _array_strs`. Чтобы получить тип `struct _array_strs` объявление должно быть таким

```
struct _array_strs
{
   int count;
   char **arrays;
};
```

Вы можете совместить оба варианта

```
typedef struct _array_strs
{
   int count;
   char **arrays;
} _array_strs;
```

что сделает `_array_strs` и `struct _array_strs` синонимами. Однако использовать эти имена вперемешку не рекомендуется. Выберите одно.

Что характерно, в объявлении функции `getArrayFromFile` у вас использовано правильное имя типа для вашего исходного варианта (просто `_array_strs`), но затем в коде вдруг непонятно откуда полез какой-то `struct _array_strs`. Почему? В общем, сначала определитесь, как именно вы хотите называть свой тип и соответствующим образом исправьте его объявление и ссылки на его название в коде.

Во-вторых, в текущей версии под сам объект `_array_strs` выделить память несложно

```
_array_strs *array_strs = malloc(sizeof *array_strs);
...
array_strs->count = i;
array_strs->arrays = arrays;
```

и все. У вас же там под `calloc` понаписана какая-то бессмысленная каша. Если вам зачем-то хочется воспользоваться именно `calloc`, то

```
_array_strs *array_strs = calloc(1, sizeof *array_strs);
...
```

Имейте в виду, что ваше "динамическое поле `arrays`" это никакое не "динамическое поле", а обычный указатель. На выделение памяти для самой структуры оно никак не влияет вообще. В вашем коде подразумевается, что память для `char **arrays` выделена где-то внутри `getPtrMatrix` и выделена правильно. Не ясно только, почему на результат `getPtrMatrix` сделан явный каст `(char **)`. Почему?

В-третьих, в языке С объявления функции со списком параметров `()` являются deprecated. Возьмите в привычку писать `(void)`. Хотя функция без параметров - это в большинстве случаев странно.

P.S. Ну и, конечно, "классика жанра" - цикл с предусловием `while (!feof(fd))`, который приведет к вопросам типа "почему у меня `array_strs->count` на единицу больше, чем надо".

Comment: Огромное спасибо. На все Ваши вопросы, у меня один ответ, - банальное не знание матчасти.
По поводу, calloc, а не malloc. Смутило, что malloc не обнуляет выделенную память, после Вашего ответа, догадываюсь, что в этом месте, обнуление бессмысленно?
По поводу явного (char **), если не делать, компилятор ругается. В прототипе функции, возвращается (void **). Функция может вернуть int матрицу. Нагуглил "советы" что надо приводить явно (char **). Возможно в СИ так не положено, и эстетичней будет разделить это на две функции?
Ещё раз спасибо. Я завтра всё протестирую, и в выберу Ваш ответ.

Comment: Поправлю, пустой список параметров по средствам `()` последние 20 лет только собираются объявить устаревшим, так как он кукует в `6.11 Future language directions`, что в c99, что в с11.

Comment: @Fat-Zer: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под "собираются объявить". Устаревшим (obsolescent) его официально объявили уже очень давно, еще в самом первом стандарте C89/90 (см. 6.9.4, т.е. те самые "Future language directions"). А вот действительно окончательно выкосить его все не решаются. Каждая фича языка устраняется в два разнесенных по времени этапа: 1) объявление obsolescent, 2) фактическое устранение. `()` прошел только первый этап, где и завис.

Comment: @AnT, Я понимаю секцию "Future language directions", как «планы на будущее», то что может быть будет принято в будущих стандартах, нежели как нечто жёстко закреплённое. Я не прав? [вопрос без сарказма]

Comment: @Fat-Zer: Весь текст стандарта является *нормативным*, кроме примеров, замечаний, сносок и разделов, явно помеченных как *информативные*. Раздел "Future language directions" является нормативным, поэтому если там уже сейчас сказано, что это obsolescent feature, то это уже сейчас obsolescent feature. А "future" заключается в том, что когда-нибудь эту obsolescent feature таки выкосят нафиг.

Comment: @AnT, ок, спасибо.

Comment: @AnT, ещё такой вопрос, если не затруднит? Смотрите, область памяти arrays, присваивается указателю в поле структуры. Если в конце функции я освобожу память переменной free(arrays), это не повлияет на значения поля структуры? Правильно ли, так подчищать память или не стоит?